# How to efficiently query a date-partitioned table while doing column filter

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a date-partitioned that I query with some timestamp condition like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE _PARTITIONTIME BETWEEN TIMESTAMP("2017-07-01")
  AND TIMESTAMP("2017-07-13")
```

I also want to filter on additional columns (*after* the partition filter). I thought doing this would work

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE _PARTITIONTIME BETWEEN TIMESTAMP("2017-07-01") 
  AND TIMESTAMP("2017-07-13")
  AND col = "val"
```

But this bumped the estimated processed size 20 times up, so I guess it cancels the `_PARTITIONTIME` filter. Looking at this https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-partitioned-tables#scanning_all_partitions I then tried pushing the query in a sub query and then do the filter in the outer query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM table
     WHERE _PARTITIONTIME BETWEEN TIMESTAMP("2017-07-01") 
       AND TIMESTAMP("2017-07-13")
  )
WHERE col = "val"
```

But it yielded the same estimated processed size as the precedent query. How can I do this ?

Comment: Off the top of my head, perhaps the query optimizer doesn't know that it should check the partition first, and so is checking _every_ partition for the `col` value first.  This could explain such a large 20 fold decrease in performance.

Comment: This doesn't make sense--the filter should still apply. Please provide a more complete sample of your query, e.g. including any joins. You are using standard SQL, right?

Comment: Also please provide job ids for the queries so we can investigate further.

Comment: @Quentin Sommer, can you elaborate your answer a little so the others can get an idea of how to solve related issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had one side effect sub-query somewhere else that wasn't affecting the computing cost until I use a column from its result.

The filter is indeed now working properly without this side effect